# Moving Subversion from one server to another

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I used the svnadmin dump to dump our repositories to flat files. I have a cmd file that runs through them all. I then used another cmd file that first creates the repository on the new server using svnadmin create repositoryname, and then it loads the flat file information into it's corresponding repository. So, It looks like this:

- Server 1:

  ```
  svnadmin dump repository1 --incremental > z:\newserversharedrive\repositories\dumpfile1
  ```
- Server 2:

  ```
  svnadmin create repository1
  svnadmin load e:\..\repositories\repository1 < dumpfile1
  ```

The problem is that once this is done, the `svnserve.conf` file from the old repository did not get copied into server 2.

Is there a way to script this using `svnadmin` so the `svnserve.conf` files also get copied?

Without this, i would have to go into each repository's conf directory and make edits to the `svnserve.conf` file.

Thank you,
bramoin

Answer (score 1):

I asked our SVN admins, and they gave me the following advice:

- They use `svnserve.conf` not, instead they use ApacheSVN.
- They don't think your art of copying the repository from one server to the other is state of the art. Instead, they use the following technique:

  ```
  Computer A (old server)
  Computer B (new server)

  Login on computer B and from there do:
  #svnadmin create repoB
  #ssh -C compA "svnadmin dump /pathA/repoA" | svnadmin load /pathB/repoB --force-uuid
  #scp compA:/path/repoA/conf/svnserve.conf /pathB/repoB/conf/
  ```
- If you have worked further on repository on server A, you have to do the following:

  ```
  #ssh -C compA "svnadmin dump /pathA/repoA --incremental -r oldcopiedRev:oldlastRev"  | svnadmin load /pathB/repoB
  ```

  You will then get the missing revision to server B.

Have you tried to just copy the `svnserve.conf` file from one server to the other? I have not found any information that depends on the server, IP, ... of the old or new server, so a copy should just work.

Comment: While this is a nice answer, the person asking the question is running on Windows (note the `cmd file` and the reference to `e:\..\repositories\repository1`). :)

Comment: Well, you are right. I will let it stay, perhaps it is useful for others.